# List of computers with name, serial number and user in text file BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to know if there is a way to batch file to list (if possible accéssible from the network at launch) all computers with the next serial number and the user logged on the machine to the moment?

I would like to update an inventory. I made a script that asks for the name / first name and displays the name of the PC and the SN but it forces the user to either execute manuellemmente and I copy the results to a text file on the network or via GPO but it bothers me a little.

And I have a problem with the wmic bios get serialnumber, when I refer to a text file, there is a space after each letter ...

Thank you in advance !

Edit :
here's the code I did. It is necessary that the user starts it or even that executes from a GPO.

```
@echo off
cls
set /p name= Last Name : 
set /p first= First Name : 
cls
echo %computername% > D:\%last%.txt
echo %name% %first% >> D:\%last%.txt
wmic bios get serialnumber >> D:\%last%.txt
```

Comment: My code is very far from what I want, this is why I come to ask for help ...

Comment: @sozed most users here are not willing to do your work for you, but are willing to help you get yours done. So best is to start by showing what you have, even if it is not much or completly wrong - show us that you are trying.

Comment: Original post edited

Comment: How is this question linked to tag [tag:spritebatch]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `MORE`

```
wmic bios get serialnumber | more >> D:\%last%.txt
```

This should convert the UCS2 encoded output from wmic to ANSI encoding

Comment: It work thank you !

Comment: It works sorry, it's my fault, false manipulation.
Now I'll find a way to do it remotely on any machine ..

Comment: @Sozed `wmic /node` - see `wmic /?` and `wmic /node /?`

Comment: Hi @Stephan, i try this code `wmic /node:@computerlist.txt bios get SerialNumber /format:htable>ServerSerialNumbers.htm
start "" ServerSerialNumbers.htm`but don't work this error return : ''Failed to open Node-list file (Please check the filename)."

Comment: do you _have_ a `computerlist.txt`? (in the current directory?)

Comment: @Sozed Please open a new question, do not try to ask more questions in the comment section

Comment: jeb we will say that my original question was not resolved 100% .. 
@Stephan yes